# Connect one SIP phone to multiple Asterisk Servers

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip

I am working on a project where there are multiple apartment complexes that share the same reception desk, it's just one of the buildings. There are VOIP devices in those apartments that have to be able to communicate with the reception. However, each building has it's own asterisk server installed already.

I've looked into this and one solution seems to be call forwarding via vlan trunking, but I am under time constraints and if there is a simple way to have each of the buildings connect to one central reception then that would be great.

Is it possible for a single SIP phone to have several simultaneous connections to different asterisk servers and make and receive calls from and to them? For example, if an IP phone supports 6 lines and 6 SIP accounts; are all of those lines and accounts limited to one asterisk server or could it be connected to 6 different servers? ( via a switch as most IP phones only have 2 ethernet ports)

So is this a viable solution?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you are interested in the product, please contact the vendor.

Comment: You'd have better luck with this on serverfault.com.  Most SIP phones these days support multiple accounts, pick a model and check the manual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer you question, **yes, it is possible**. If the phone has multiple accounts you can register each one to a different PBX/proxy. Just make sure the phone can reach all of the IP/hosts you need it to register to.

Depending on the brand of the phone, you can make all calls to the reception desk use the right account to dial, and everything else use their default PBX. You can even setup a fast dial button. This way the user doesn't need to use certain line or follow special instructions to call the desk.